# What does "string literal in condition" mean?

Tags: ruby, string, conditional-statements, literals

Whenever I try to run the program, an error pops up saying "string literal in condition (on line 10)". What am I doing wrong?

```
puts "Welcome to the best calculator there is. Would you like to (a) calculate the area of a geometric shape or (b) calculate the equation of a parabola? Please enter an 'a' or a 'b' to get started."
response = gets.chomp

if response == "a" or "A"

       puts "ok."

elsif response == "b" or "B"

       puts "awesome."

else

       puts "I'm sorry. I did not get that. Please try again."

end
```

Comment: The problem does not seem to be actually on line 10 within what you posted. If you post something different from the code you run to get the message, then it is useless to write `(on line 10)`. Do not write such confusing things.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

You have to specify the full condition on both sides of the `or`.

```
if response == "a" or response == "A"
```

The two sides of the `or` are not connected; Ruby makes no assumptions about what's on the right based on what's on the left.  If the right side is the bare string `"A"`, well, anything other than `false` or `nil` is considered "true", so the whole expression evaluates as "true" all the time. But Ruby notices that it's a string and not actually a boolean value, suspects you might not have specified what you meant to, and so issues the warning in the question.

You can also use a `case` expression to make it simpler to do multiple tests against a single value; if you supply a list of multiple possibilities in a single `when`, they are effectively `or`ed together:

```
case response
  when "a","A"
    puts "ok"
  when "b","B"
    puts "awesome."
  else
    puts "I'm sorry. I did not get that.  Please try again."
end
```

For the specific situation of ignoring alphabetic case, you could also just convert to either upper or lower before testing:

```
case response.upcase 
  when "A"
    puts "ok"
  when "B"
    puts "awesome."
  else
    puts "I'm sorry, I did not get that.  Please try again."
 end
```

Answer (score 4):

That's not an error, it's a warning.

You have the condition

```
response == "a" or "A"
```

Well, `response == "a"` is either `true` or `false`. If it is `true`, the condition reduces to

```
true or "A"
```

which is

```
true
```

If it is `false`, the condition reduces to

```
false or "A"
```

which is

```
"A"
```

which is *truthy*, since everything except `false` and `nil` is truthy.

So, regardless of the contents of `response`, the condition will *always* be true.

And that's what the warning is warning you about: string literals are always truthy, it just doesn't make sense to use them in a condition.

Answer (score 3):

It is not wrong syntactically; it is wrong in the sense that it is useless. The expression `response == "a" or "A"` is interpreted as `(response == "a") or "A"`, which is always truthful because of `"A"`, so it is useless to put that in a condition.

Answer (score 2):

`if response == "a" or "A"` is equivalent to `if (response == "a") or "A"`. And "A" is a string literal, that's why the ruby interpreter complains.