# Deleting lines containing specific words in text file in Ruby

Tags: ruby, string

I have a text file like this:

```
User accounts for \\AGGREP-1

-------------------------------------------------------------------------------
Administrator            users                    grzesieklocal
Guest                    scom                     SUPPORT_8855
The command completed successfully.
```

First line is empty line. I want to delete every empty lines in this file and every line containing words "User accounts for", "-------", "The command". I want to have only lines containing users. I don't want to delete only first 4 and the last one lines, because it can be more users in some systems and file will contain more lines.
I load file using

```
a = IO.readlines("test.txt")
```

Is any way to delete lines containing specific words?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bruby%5D+delete+line+in+file

Comment: I do not see the issue with deleting first four and last one line - it does not matter how many lines there are inbetween. If you want to go unixy (and dirty) you could to `IO.readlines("| tail -n +4 test.txt | head -n -1")`, but you will find better and real answers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

## Solution

This structure reads the file line by line, and write a new file directly :

```
def unwanted?(line)
  line.strip.empty? ||
    line.include?('User accounts') ||
    line.include?('-------------') ||
    line.include?('The command completed')
end

File.open('just_users.txt', 'w+') do |out|
  File.foreach('test.txt') do |line|
    out.puts line unless unwanted?(line)
  end
end
```

If you're familiar with regexp, you could use :

```
def unwanted?(line)
  line =~ /^(User accounts|------------|The command completed|\s*$)/
end
```

## Warning from your code

The message `warning: string literal in condition` appears when you try to use :

```
string = "nothing"

if string.include? "a" or "b"
  puts "FOUND!"
end
```

It outputs :

```
parse_text.rb:16: warning: string literal in condition
FOUND!
```

Because it should be written :

```
string = 'nothing'

if string.include?('a') || string.include?('b')
  puts "FOUND!"
end
```

See [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21556673/what-does-string-literal-in-condition-mean) question for more info.

Answer (score 1):

`IO::readlines` returns an array, so you could use `Array#select` to select just the lines you need. Bear in mind that this means that your whole input file will be in memory, which might be a problem, if the file is really large.

An alternative approach would be to use `IO::foreach`, which processes one line at a time:

```
selected_lines = []
IO.foreach('test.txt') { |line| selected_lines << line if line_matches_your_requirements }
```

Comment: It would be ok but I don't know what words I'm searching. The file is command output (net user) and I don't know users in system. But I know that I don't need lines containing specific words. After deleting that lines I can easy use only usernames.

Comment: You use `foreach` to avoid getting a huge array, and then you create a possibly huge array with `selected_lines` ;)

Comment: @mila002 then your criteria is that the lines do not contain specific words! Selection and Deletion is just the same as applying the inverse criteria here (something like `!line_starts_with_dash(line)` vs `line_starts_with_dash(line)`).

Comment: Using it `selected_lines = []
IO.foreach('test.txt') { |line| selected_lines << line if line_matches_your_requirements }` I get an error `winuser.rb:22: warning: string literal in condition`

Comment: @EricDuminil: I don't know whether the number of selected lines is huge or not; from the example posted, it's only the lines containing the word *user*, so they are much less. In any case, the OP wants to collect all those words, so no matter how many they are, he plans to have them in memory.

Comment: @mila002: Post the exact code as you have written it. The way you explain it in your comment does not make sense.

Comment: The OP mentionned deleting lines, I don't know if he wants to have the remaining ones in memory at once. And you explicitely wrote about a really large file, so I just commented that your code isn't coherent with your remark.